# Unity fails to build game for android

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

Recently I have build a new PC for my home. I setup my PC just as like my PC at my office. But when I try to build a game that I'm working on currently. I can build for android perfectly on my office PC, but My pc at home can't. Gives me some kind of error. Sometimes even shows `Blue Screen` and restarts. Both PC's has same Unity version installed.
I'm not sure if it is software problem or hardware problem. 
My PC configuration is:

Motherboard: `Assus PRIME Z790 P CSM (WiFi)`

Processor: `14900K`

RAM: `G. Skill Trident Z5 DDR5 6000MHz 16GB X2`

GPU: `MSI GEFORCE RTX 4070 Ti GAMING X TRIO`

Below is the error message:

```
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\iz17e\q9xdm0lmm4eb.o failed with output:
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: C:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -marm -D__ARM_ARCH_7__ -D__ARM_ARCH_7A__ -D__ANDROID_UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOLS_ARE_WEAK__ -faddrsig -mllvm -hoist-common-insts=1 -DANDROID -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -no-canonical-prefixes -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fomit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -Wswitch -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-implicitly-unsigned-literal -Wno-integer-overflow -Wno-shift-negative-value -Wno-unknown-attributes -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -fvisibility=hidden -fexceptions -fno-rtti -g -Os -fPIC -fno-strict-overflow -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DBASELIB_INLINE_NAMESPACE=il2cpp_baselib -DIL2CPP_MONO_DEBUGGER_DISABLED -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DHAVE_BDWGC_GC -DNDEBUG -I. "-ID:/Unity Projects/Unity_Boat_Blitz_v2/Boat Blitz Clone/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp" -IC:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/libil2cpp/pch -IC:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/libil2cpp -IC:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/external/baselib/Include -IC:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/libil2cpp/os/ClassLibraryPAL/brotli/include -IC:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/external/baselib/Platforms/Android/Include -o Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/iz17e/q9xdm0lmm4eb.o -fcolor-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -target armv7a-linux-androideabi22 -fstrict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-format=msvc -c -x c++ "D:/Unity Projects/Unity_Boat_Blitz_v2/Boat Blitz Clone/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Unity.RenderPipelines.Universal.Runtime__1.cpp"
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'D:/Unity Projects/Unity_Boat_Blitz_v2/Boat Blitz Clone/Library/Bee/artifacts/Android/il2cppOutput/cpp/Unity.RenderPipelines.Universal.Runtime__1.cpp'.
4.  Running pass 'ARM Instruction Selection' on function '@ClipperOffset_DoMiter_m7050BFCD4EA5A0BF0DE873A01698D1D61F9F42F8'
 #0 0x00007ff7fca431c8 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1c931c8)
 #1 0x00007ff7fc69ade4 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x18eade4)
 #2 0x00007ff7fc69ab55 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x18eab55)
 #3 0x00007ff7fc69a2ac (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x18ea2ac)
 #4 0x00007ff7fc697ee5 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x18e7ee5)
 #5 0x00007ff7fb7a7514 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x9f7514)
 #6 0x00007ff7fb57af23 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x7caf23)
 #7 0x00007ff7fafea748 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x23a748)
 #8 0x00007ff7faff0f53 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x240f53)
 #9 0x00007ff7fafeaf72 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x23af72)
#10 0x00007ff7fc02d1e1 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x127d1e1)
#11 0x00007ff7fc388683 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x15d8683)
#12 0x00007ff7fd6c4b13 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x2914b13)
#13 0x00007ff7fc2f0374 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1540374)
#14 0x00007ff7fb479da0 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6c9da0)
#15 0x00007ff7fb4f4473 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x744473)
#16 0x00007ff7fadb6482 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6482)
#17 0x00007ff7fadb4661 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x4661)
#18 0x00007ff7fc104156 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1354156)
#19 0x00007ff7fb327d11 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x577d11)
#20 0x00007ff7fc103bf4 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1353bf4)
#21 0x00007ff7fb442424 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x692424)
#22 0x00007ff7fb442809 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x692809)
#23 0x00007ff7fb455786 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x6a5786)
#24 0x00007ff7fadb3dcd (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x3dcd)
#25 0x00007ff7fadb1395 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x1395)
#26 0x00007ff7fadb14c8 (C:\UnityEditors\2022.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe+0x14c8)
#27 0x00007fff6093257d (C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x1257d)
#28 0x00007fff6158aa58 (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x5aa58)
clang++: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Android (7714059, based on r416183c1) clang version 12.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7cf2016289302412d708641d52d2f7ee)
Target: armv7a-unknown-linux-android22
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:/UnityEditors/2022.3.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Fahim\AppData\Local\Temp\Unity-518d1e.cpp
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: C:\Users\Fahim\AppData\Local\Temp\Unity-518d1e.sh
clang++: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Can someone tell me how can I fix this.

Comment: Change scripting backend from mono to il2cpp 
Steps : project settings -> player -> Other settings -> Configuration

Comment: @Uzair yes. scripting backend is already set to il2cpp. As I said in the question. The builds fine on my Office PC but fails on my new Home PC. I cloned the project from github so all setting is identical to that of my office PC.

Comment: did you try deleting library folder and reopen and build.

Comment: Yeah, My colleague suggested it and I did it but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of internet searching and discussing with others I found a solution for my problem.

Usually when you use dual RAM sticks you install them on 2-4 or 1-3 slots of your motherboard. In my case it was 2-4 slots. I confirmed it by reading the user manual and on the web. But for some reason it was causing problem for Unity when I tried to build my project for android.

So now I installed my RAM sticks on 3-4 slots. Basically, instead of dual channel now I'm using single channel and unity seems to like it. I can build my projects with no problem.